# (How) can I get contacts with no name to display the Organization instead of "Unnamed" on my Android phone?

Tags: contacts, htc-evo

I have an HTC Evo with contacts that were imported by Sprint from my old Palm Centro. On the Centro, I could have contacts with no name but a business/organization, and the contact list would use that as the display, and I could search on that field. (Handy for calling pizza restaurants!) On my new Android device, that sort of contact shows up as "Unknown", and the Organization name can't be searched.

1. Is there a way to get the Android contact list to mimic the Palm's (quite reasonable and user-friendly!) behavior?
2. Is there a quick way to copy the Organizations into the (say) Last Name field, if the above is not possible?
3. What is the "right way" to deal with contacts that are businesses, not people, on Android devices?

Answer (score 2):

On my HTC Magic, I just put the business name in the contact's name field, then have all the businesses in a Contacts group called "Businesses" for when I want to find one of them quickly. To be honest this is also the way I used to do it on my old Palm, too.

Comment: +1.  This is what I've always done.

Comment: Good plan, but it's a little late, as I have dozens of contacts that show up as Unnamed!

Comment: I imported everything from my old phone and this is really annoying. It uses the phone number (2121235515) instead of the company name ("Apple inc").  Who was asleep at the switch here?  Terrible contacts design and I can't edit this on Google Contacts because these imported addresses don't sync.

Comment: @Warren make sure the imported contacts are "Google" contacts and not "Phone" contacts. "Phone" contacts won't sync

Answer (score 0):

On my evo when I add a contact with an organization and no name the organization is the displayed name.  Maybe try going to a contact and hitting edit? This might get the phone to prepare the contact.

Comment: I concur. For me as well, when I *add* a *new* contact with an organization and no name, I get the organization as the displayed name. But for the existing records imported by Sprint, I get Unknown. So this doesn't solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, my contacts were sorted by organization and name, but something happened that my contacts were linked and the organization name dropped off. If you go to those contacts that just show number, click Edit, then Link, and then from the drop-down, select the organization name...too much work for something that was working fine, but that was my work-around.